# how to pass command line argument in fabric

Tags: python, fabric

I am new in fabric. I am trying to pass two command after the function of `fabfile.py`
I am trying like that

```
fab fabfile.py taskA /idep/etl/config.xml , lbs
```

Here `taskA` is a function.

But it is not working. It throws error like "No such file or directory: 'taskA'".
How can I pass the arguments? Actually I'm trying to forwarding port to remote machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is documented [here](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.9/usage/fab.html#per-task-arguments). After you setup the task to take arguments, you would then do something akin to this:

`fab taskA:'/idep/etl/config.xml,lbs'`

*note*: if you are using a fabfile named `fabfile.py` the fab command assumes this, and does not need the extra specification (which you also did w/o using the `-f` flag)

*also note*: you can specify hosts to act on, via the cli, with the `-H --hosts` flags

To get a better handle on these sorts of things you really should go through the [tutorial](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.9/tutorial.html).